# Starcraft 2 Editor: Test Melee Maps

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

How can I test my Starcraft 2 melee map?  When I go to test map, it launches the map but I don't have a base or any units.  The map has 8 starting positions and started out as a 256x256 map I imported from Starcraft 1.

Maybe I have something in the map setup incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you increase the number of players to 8? (via the game options, not by simply placing 8 different start locations)

Did you make any changes with triggers? (Melee initialization is what's done on all new maps, which is exactly what you want, so if you changed it, your map won't work as you'd hope)

Comment: When you create a new map, it automatically adds triggers for melee.  My starcraft 1 imported map has none of those triggers.  I'm not sure how to add them.

Comment: I added the triggers manually, but now my initial scv's are placed a good distance from my command center, and the command center can't build new scv's no matter where I land it "position blocked".  I checked my pathing, and nothing was set anywhere on the map.

Comment: Can you perhaps upload the map file into the OP?

Comment: Good idea.  http://yage3d.net/host/TheLostv5.SC2Map

Comment: Looks like you've got a couple problems. I assume most (if not all) of this is due to some problem that occured while importing. Firstly, check your bounds. Some of the start locations and minerals are actually off the playable map area. Second, you've got major pathing problems. I don't know what caused these, or how to fix them, but you've got weird, invisible pathing "trenches" (for lack of a better word) that inhibit movement. Again, I don't know what's causing this. Finally, some of your start locations appear too close to the minerals (they're in the yellow grided squares).

Comment: There's also the issue of hatcheries not producing larva. That in particular suggests that something is fundamentally wrong with the map, though that may be related to the pathing, as mentioned previously.

Comment: I don't see any pathing drawn when I click the pathing at the top.  How do you see these invisble pathing trenches?

Comment: Keep restarting the map until you get one of the starting positions where your workers start in a vertical line. They are stuck on that vertical line, unable to move left or right. I admit freely that I don't know what causes this.

Comment: Nevermind, I "see" (feel) them when I run the map and try to move my probes around and they follow weird paths.  I guess I'll recreate from scratch.

Comment: I've *heard* that you can copy+paste map terrain. If that's true, you could start from scratch but then paste in the terrain instead of recreating it by hand. I figure you're at least less likely to have hosed pathing / bounds / whatever that way. GL!

Comment: I had tried that earlier.  Didn't work.  Nice suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Joe, I had the same problem.  I copied the trigger from another game and pasted.  Then needed to adjust some of the ground/ramps, followed by starting locations.